# Constructing upper bound while proving a functional limit

Tags: real-analysis

> Show that  $$\lim_{x \to 2} g(x) = 4$$ where $g(x) =  x^{2}$.

I know $|g(x) - 4| = |x^2 - 4| = |x + 2| |x - 2|$ and I can make $|x-2|$ to be as small as I like by choosing suitable  $\delta$. However, I need an upper bound on $|x + 2|$ in order to how how small of $\delta$ should I choose.

The textbook says something as following which I don't understand:

> We get the upper bound $| x + 2| \le |3 + 2| = 5$ $\forall x \in  V_{\delta}(c)$.
>   Then, choose $\delta$ = $min \left\{ 1, \epsilon/5 \right\}$.
>   $0 < |x - 2| <  \delta  \rightarrow |x^2 - 4| = |x + 2| |x - 2| < (5) \frac{ \epsilon }{5} =  \epsilon  $

I don't understand why 3 is chosen for x in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the three is because $3=2+1=c+\delta$. To find the delta to choose, we either take something based on $\epsilon$ for when they are both really small, or we pick some constant that will work for the proof, in this case in order to bound one problematic term. We then take the smallest of those two values. The idea is that if we know that $\delta \leq 1$, then the problematic term in the problem is bounded like so: $|c+delta+2| \leq 5$.